# Подытожить строки в stdClass Object

Tags: php

Переменная rows из базы равна тому, что ниже:

```html
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [consumption] => 200.00
            [id] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [consumption] => 500.00
            [id] => 2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [consumption] => 100.00
            [id] => 2
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [consumption] => 150.00
            [id] => 2
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [consumption] => 150.00
            [id] => 8
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [consumption] => 150.00
            [id] => 8
        )

)

for ($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++)
{
 $row = $rows[$i];
}
```

id идут по возрастанию, можно и по убыванию сделать. На выходе получается примерно следующее:

```html
id     consumption
2      200.00
2      500.00
2      100.00
2      150.00
8      150.00
8      150.00
```

Хотелось бы сделать примерно следующее: Чтобы по окончании каждого id добавлялась еще строка с суммой consumption каждого id. Т.е. должно получиться примерно так:

```html
id     consumption
2      200.00
2      500.00
2      100.00
2      150.00
       750.00
8      150.00
8      150.00
       300.00
```

Не понимаю как это сделать, поэтому прошу помощи...

Comment: Мониторить текущее значение id, как только оно изменилось - выводить накопленную сумму.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно дополнить этой суммой массив *(в конечном счете у вас выводится нужный результат)*, то можете попробовать вариант, который находится ниже:

```
$array = [
    ['consumption' => '200.00', 'id' => 2],
    ['consumption' => '500.00', 'id' => 2],
    ['consumption' => '100.00', 'id' => 2],
    ['consumption' => '150.00', 'id' => 2],
    ['consumption' => '150.00', 'id' => 8],
    ['consumption' => '150.00', 'id' => 8],
];

$new = [];

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    if (!isset($new[$value['id']])) {
        $new[$value['id']] = 0;
    }

    $new[$value['id']] += (int) $value['consumption'];
}

$result = [];

foreach ($array as $key => $row)
{
    $result[] = $row;

    if (!isset($array[$key + 1]['id']) || $array[$key + 1]['id'] != $row['id'])
    {
        $result[] = [
            'consumption' => $new[$row['id']]
        ];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: спасибо, ваш код работает, но он полностью основан на массиве, а у меня на stdClass Object Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [consumption] => 200.00
            [id] => 2
        ))

Comment: И поэтому я не соображу как все это переделать...

Comment: Попробуйте преобразовать его: `$array = (array) $основной_массив;`

Comment: Конечно же это не сработает (

Comment: Я смогу полностью преобразовать в (array), но обратно в stdClass Object не получится сделать, поэтому придется переделывать все в цикле for ($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++)

Comment: @skillful, почему же обратно нет? Вот же: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cc345a217f6f944cee014e2a6d78f66881f2cb73

Comment: Не. У меня на выходе Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object   У вас: stdClass Object
(
    [0] => Array (Наоборот)

Comment: @skillful, понял, сейчас подумаю

Comment: @skillful, посмотрите это http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/079a85947913741977c6a220f75dccadc0ee910d

Comment: Похоже, все получится. Дайте время на проверку... ))

Comment: Да, все четко. Напишите в лс.

Comment: @skillful, мой ВК - vk.com/id19933